# Kivy button loses visual indication of being pressed when I add in functionality

Tags: python, user-interface, button, kivy, kivy-language

I'm working on integrating some robots into my work's warehouse. I've created a Kivy GUI to operate these robots. Normally when you press a button in Kivy, the button shape shifts from rectangular to a rounded rectangle and the button color changes. It maintains this response if I add in simple functionality, like it printing words when pressed. However, when I add in code to control the robots, it loses this visual indication. The button works - when pressed it executes the proper function, but there is no change in the button's appearance to indicate it has been pressed.

I don't know how much code I can provide since it is proprietary. I'm using the robot company's API and SDK to create this GUI.

I've tried making buttons both using a .kv file and without. I've tried manually adding in color changes when the button is pressed - no luck. I've also tried making transparency changes and text changes. Basically I can't get any visual change to happen to the button when it is pressed while it calls this function.

from my .kv file (sorry the formatting came out weird):

```
< Button >:
    font_size: 30
    color: 1,1,1,1
    size_hint: 0.15,0.1
< FloatLayout >:
    Button:
        text: "Clear Error"
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {"x":0.85, "top":0.1}
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: .2,.8,.2,1
        on_press: app.ClearError()
```

from my .py file:

```
def ClearError(self):
    robot_name1 = "robot name"
    print("CLEAR ERROR")
    robot = Robot.load(robot_name1, client=client)
    if robot.error_status is not None:
        print("Error status!")
        robot.error_status = None 
        robot.save(client=client)
```

Comment: Try changing `<Button>:` to `<MyButton@Button>:` and `Button:` to `MyButton:` in your `.kv` file. See if that has any effect. I am wondering if there are some other settings that are affecting your `Button`.

Comment: Actually, what you describe as "normal" kivy behavior is not "normal". `Button` shapes do not normally change when pressed. So it is apparent that your company's API and/or SDK is changing the default behavior of `Buttons`.

Comment: Another thing to try is change `on_press:` to `on_release:`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson thank you, your simple fix worked!